# How to get individual values from Facebook json response

Tags: java, facebook, json, facebook-graph-api, struts2

**What my application Does:** 
               I have implemented facebook login for my website. And i want to  save some user info from facebook graph api which i am getting response through Json.

**My problem:**
           I am able to print some Individual  values from json response *but unable to print values which are nested inside the array*.
            How can i print the child values from json response?

```
       *Please see my code below. There i am able to print users info like name and id.
         But unable to get the location of  user from json response.*
```

**Json Output:**

```
        --responseBody---{"id":"100003645579131","name":"Ashutosh Singh","first_name":"Ashutosh","location":{"id":"106377336067638","name":"Bangalore, India"}}
        ---json---{"work":[{"position":{"id":"140001066034322","name":"Senior Inspector"},"location":{"id":"106377336067638","name":"Bangalore, India"},"name":"Ashutosh Singh","last_name":"Singh","gender":"male"}
```

**My code** to print above values:

```
String newUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" + accessToken;
            httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(newUrl);
            System.out.println("Get info from facebook --> executing request: "+ httpget.getURI()); 
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httpget, responseHandler);
               System.out.println("--responseBody---"+responseBody);
            json = (JSONObject) JSONSerializer.toJSON(responseBody);
            System.out.println("---json---"+json);
            facebookId = json.getString("id");//this values are printing fine
            String firstName = json.getString("first_name");//this values are printing fine
            String lastName = json.getString("last_name");//this values are printing fine

            String location=json.getJSONArray("location").toString(); //Unable to print information. Plz give help me. I want to print the location name from the json results.

            System.out.println("locale:"+location); //Unable to print
```

**Error Message:**

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: net.sf.json.JSONException: JSONObject["location"] is not a JSONArray.
            org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processException(RequestProcessor.java:520)
            org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:427)
            org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:228)
            org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
            org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:449)
            javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
            javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        root cause

        net.sf.json.JSONException: JSONObject["location"] is not a JSONArray.
            net.sf.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:1793)
            com.ebhasin.bstalentscareers.action.SecurityServlet.getUserMailAddressFromJsonResponse(SecurityServlet.java:88)
            com.ebhasin.bstalentscareers.action.FacebookLoginAction.execute(FacebookLoginAction.java:45)
            org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:425)
            org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:228)
            org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
            org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:449)
            javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
            javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from JSON, location is not a JSON Array , but a JSON Object. You are using getJSONArray() to retrieve it. Use getJSONObject() instead.

Comment: hi, But how can i print the value(work->name) from this response? ->>         json---{"work":[{"position":{"id":"140001066034322","name":"Senior Inspector"},"location":{"id":"106377336067638","name":"Bangalore, India"},"employer":{"id":"109396455744864","name":"Police Officer"},"start_date":"0000-00"}]}

Comment: first get JSONObject work, then get JSONObject position from it. From this, get a JSONObject having key as "name".

Comment: i tried this but its NOT working->>                  JSONObject work=json.getJSONObject("work");
                   JSONObject position=work.getJSONObject("position"); 
                    JSONObject posname=position.getJSONObject("name");
                     System.out.println("--posname----"+posname);

Comment: try debugging or printing each value after each step and check what value is coming as null.

Comment: debugger is reaching only upto JSONObject work=json.getJSONObject("work"); and after that it is showing error